# Generate li with interval and resize all to fit window horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css, setinterval

I am using jquery to create li with each interval up to 5 times only. And with each li the border-width also increases. Problem is I want all li to fit in the window/page horizontally aligned.

What I did on each interval I resize the li width by getting the window width and divide it with the current li length. But each li has different border-width so I need to also compute that.

This is what I have so far.

```
<style>
    * { margin:0; padding:0;}
    ul { list-style:none; height:300px; width:100%;}
    li { display:block; float:left; height:100%; border:1px solid blue;}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();

    var interval = setInterval(function(){

        var li = $('<li>');

        var l = $('li').length+1;

        li.css('border-width', l);

        $('ul').append(li);

        $('li').width((w-l*2)/l);

        if($('li').length > 4){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set CSS `box-sizing:border-box` to your `<li>` so you won't have to worry about the `border-width` calculation, then set its **width in percentage**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var w = $(window).width();

    var interval = setInterval(function(){

        var li = $('<li>');

        var l = $('li').length+1;

        li.css('border-width', l);

        $('ul').append(li);

        $('li').css({'width':(100/l)+'%'});

        if($('li').length > 4){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

    }, 2000);

});
```

Also check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/wzEK7/)

Comment: I tried what you said but not working can you post at least the jquery code please?

Comment: Yey this is what I want to achieve! Many thanks to you Mark S